# Is there any way to differentiate between Ram/Storage? Feature Extraction from Phone titles

Tags: text, data-science, text-processing

I am currently extracting the features such as color, brand , ram, rom, storage etc from the titles of products. The problems arises with some product like "Infinix Hot S3X - X622 64GB 4GB". A person can tell that the 64GB is storage and 4GB is RAM, but can somehow computer differentiate between them?

I was thinking that anything with GB and above 15 should automatically be considered as storage but it doesn't feels right.

Sorry if it is common problem, I am very new to text processing.

Comment: If there are two measurements, it seems fairly certain the larger will be storage.

Comment: there are some product which has either RAM or storage.

Comment: There is no way programmatically to determine which is which, other than making the presumption that the larger number is storage. Why would you think there would be? I have 32 GB of RAM in my laptop, and it's capable of supporting 256 GB. How would your *anything above 15* work with that?